# NameError: name 'bs4' is not defined

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

When I run the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

response = urllib.urlopen('file:///Users/kerss/diet/sesame_seeds.html')
html = response.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

span = soup.find("span", id="NUTRIENT_0")
print(span.text)
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "c:\users\kerss\diet\scrape.py", line 8, in <module>
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
NameError: name 'bs4' is not defined
```

but bs4 is defined? or not?

Comment: Just use `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`

Comment: Did you copy that line from somewhere else by chance ? Did you check the imports on that code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`

Answer (score 5):

Change `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` to `import bs4`